# Inno Setup custom welcome page

Tags: inno-setup

How can I customize the welcome page of an Inno Setup installer?

I want to create an installer similar to Skype's installer with only 3 pages:

1. Custom Welcome Page with some options
2. Progress Page
3. Finish Page with "Run Program" option

But all the code samples I've seen only allow customizing the wizard *after* the welcome page.

Apparently Skype uses Inno Setup, so I know this is possible. But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Inno Setup Form Designer by Marc Hoffmann, you can hide the Welcome page and instead show your own custom pages.

Comment: http://74.125.155.132/search?q=cache:DUrI8EZ9ApYJ:www.uninshs.com/faqs.php+hide+the+inno+welcome+page&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a

Comment: The first question in the google cache above give you some idea.

Comment: Also, Inno Setup Form Designer only creates wizard pages (with the banner and Back/Next/Cancel panel). I'm looking for a completely custom form like Skype's. So I'll need to use the CreateCustomForm function instead of CreateCustomPage (which the form designer uses).

Comment: Not sure, about that, whether Inno Setup Form Designer allows such things, but aren't you using the wrong thing then for your project. You might looks at alternatives. Otherwise you can write you own extension dll for INNO. Inno website will have more details.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the link. But I think I still see a quick flicker of the welcome screen. I'll do some more testing just to be sure.

Comment: As I said above, you might want to look at alternatives, if you really don't want the default INNO gui. Inno is used because its easy to create simple setups not custom setups.

Comment: Thing is, the setup is simple. I just want an alternative UI. Anyway, I accepted your answer, but the answer was really in your comments so would be great if you included that link in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. create your own custom page and skip the welcome page.
2. read CodeDlg.iss in your Inno setup folder: Inno Setup 5\Examples\
3. see [Run] section in the Inno help document.